# What does "just above chance" mean?

Tags: meaning-in-context

> Each classifier in the group is a
>   “weak” classifier (only just above
>   chance performance).

What does "only just above chance performance" mean?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're parsing it wrong: it's “just above [chance performance]". A *chance performance* is what you would obtain if you performed at random. For example, if you answer a multiple choice test randomly, you will (on average) get a score that is not zero.

So, being ***only just*** above chance performance means “being only marginally better than random”. Thus, it is not very good.